# Run dcm4chee-2.14.7-src in browser after building binary folder with ant build

Tags: java, maven, ant, dcm4che

I am a new dcm4chee developer, I'm trying to run dcm4chee-2.14.7 after ant build with eclipse according the instructions follow in this website [blog.birost.com](https://blog.birost.com/a?ID=00150-4013f87a-8c8d-4392-b0c5-862078c48f76). I have successfully build the binary folder in dcm4jboss-build **C:\dcm4chee\dcm4chee-2.14.7-src\dcm4jboss-build\bin**, but when I open my browser with this link http://localhost:8080/dcm4chee-web/, it shows nothing.